# Web page to Uri?

Tags: android, google-cloud-print

I'm working on getting Google Cloud Print into my Android app, but I don't quite get Uri's and MimeTypes, making it difficult for me to figure out where I'm going wrong.  I want to print an array of strings containing Html/Css/Javascript.  Here is my current code:

```
public void printScore(String[] pages) {

    Uri docUri = Uri.parse("<html><head><title>Hello</title></head><body>Hello, Printer!</body></html>");

//      for(int i = 0; i < pages.length; i++  ) {
//          docUri = Uri.parse("<html><head><title>Hello</title></head><body>Hello, Printer!</body></html>");       
//      }

    String docMimeType = "text/html";
    String docTitle = "My Web Pages";

    Intent printIntent = new Intent(this, PrintDialogActivity.class);
    printIntent.setDataAndType(docUri, docMimeType);
    printIntent.putExtra("title", docTitle);
    startActivity(printIntent);
}
```

This isn't working at all.  I get Google Cloud Print saying 'Document Missing'.  Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I don't know the cloud print API but an [URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_identifier) is something like `http://google.com`, `file:///sdcard/file.txt`, `content://sms/inbox/5` and so on. `Uri.parse` will not work unless you put in a Uri as a string in there. Mimetype seems to be ok. - My guess is that you should save the Strings into a file and use `Uri.fromFile(thefile)` as docUri.

Comment: That got it working, would you mind posting this as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know the cloud print API but an [URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_identifier) is something like `http://google.com`, `file:///sdcard/file.txt`, `content://sms/inbox/5` and so on.

`Uri.parse` will not work (or produce meaningful results) unless you put in a Uri as a String in there. Mimetype seems to be ok.

My guess is that you should save the Strings into a file and use `Uri.fromFile(thefile)` as `docUri`.